# How to display content that has been written to a Socket.OutputStream while maintaining a persistent connection?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, webserver

Suppose that I have a multi-threaded web server that only allow clients to perform GET requests for a couple of HTML files. I want to maintain a persistent connection (i.e HTTP Connection: keep-alive) while "dynamically" displaying the content for each request the client makes. Like if they first request `index.html` then `foo.html` etc. The problem right now is when I don't close the streams and socket, the program will hang until it happens.

Simply put, the multi-threaded web server consist of a thread pool (Java's `ExecutorService`) with a `ServerSocket` that listens to a specific port (e.g `9000`) and selects a thread from the threadpool to handle the opening of a client socket to the server. It is basically the same setup as showed in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html.

My modified setup looks like this:

`WorkerRunnable.java`:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = this.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            List<String> headers = readInputStream(input) 
            Request request = new Request(headers); 
            Response response = new Response(request);

            // response.raw() returns correctly formatted HTTP 
            output.write(response.raw().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

            // close the socket if the client specifies Connection: close 
            if (!request.keepAlive()) {
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } else {
                this.clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private List<String> readInputStream(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            headers.add(line);
        }
        return headers;
    }
```

My problem is that the HTML only will be displayed when the input/output stream (and thus also the socket) are closed. As far as I understand, the `Socket.InputStream` will basically hang until it receives an `EOF` token - which it receives when the stream closes. But if I want to maintain a persistent connection, it doesn't really make sense to close the streams and client socket. So I was wondering how to maintain a persistent connection while also displaying the content of multiple GET requests from clients (assuming this is the correct approach)? If not, please let me know if I've approached this task wrongly.

I have tried to flush the output stream as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892717/tcp-connection-server-only-sends-message-after-closing-socket?rq=1), but the problem still persists.

Comment: This feels like the XY problem. You've decided to build your own webserver from scratch, rather than use Spring or DropWizard, which would handle all of this for you. Why do you need to write your own webserver? Most folks would reuse an existing one, and just write the servlet they need.

Comment: It's part of an assessment that I have been given, and I wanted to use the opportunity to learn new things :) It's also nice to know how existing frameworks work under the hood.